# orchard bing maps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, bing-maps, orchardcms-1.6

Why when I installed the bing.maps from the modules/gallery menu of orchard...does 'bing maps' not appear on the menu on the left hand side?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't expose an admin menu item, probably. Did you try creating a content type and adding the Bing Maps part to it?

Comment: I can add bing maps through the module part, that isnt the problem.  It was just a general Q because I also added 'Image gallery' and it now appears on the left hand side menu

Comment: There will only be a menu entry if the module adds it. Some modules do, some don't. Some even add more than one. There is no obligation to do so.